# AWS Serverless Aurora - Communications link failure with primary. No active connection found for master

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-aurora-serverless

Application deployed on Amazon ECS (using Fargate) is facing issues connecting with Serverless Aurora DB.
I can successfully connect to this serverless DB using the bastion host, EC2 instance in the same VPC with public IP and SSH Tunnel.
DB connection works successfully for `provisioned` EngineMode but for `serverless` it throws the following error:

```
2020-11-23 10:31:09.378 ERROR [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool request-id: ; user-id:  - jdbc:mysql:aurora://db-cluster-endpoint.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/test_service - Exception during pool initialization. 
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Communications link failure with primary. No active connection found for master. 
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.failover.AbstractMastersListener.throwFailoverMessage(AbstractMastersListener.java:559)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.failover.impl.MastersSlavesListener.checkInitialConnection(MastersSlavesListener.java:350)
    ...
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:473)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:554)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)
```

DB Cluster Configuration: I've disabled the auto-pause feature and configured cluster such that 2 instances would be up all the time. I can see CPU utilization and capacity unit 2 in RDS (AWS Console).

```
Type: AWS::RDS::DBCluster
Properties:
  BackupRetentionPeriod: !Ref DbBackupRetentionPeriod
  DBClusterParameterGroupName: !Ref DbClusterParameterGroup
  DBSubnetGroupName: !Ref DbSubnetGroup
  Engine: aurora-mysql
  EngineMode: serverless
  ScalingConfiguration:
    AutoPause: false
    MinCapacity: 2
    MaxCapacity: 32
```

Datasource configuration:

```
<bean name="dataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource">
    <property name="jdbcUrl"
              value="#{'jdbc:mysql:aurora') + '//${database.host}:${database.port:3306}/${database.name}'}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver"/>
```

***SOLVED***:

The problem was with the access restriction for the user that a client was using to establish a DB connection.

Comment: You wrote that it works on EC2 instance? Did you run same code on the instance as the one you are running on ecs?

Comment: I did not run any code on EC2 instance. EC2 is created as a Bastion Host, same VPC and Public IP is assigned, and DB is connected via SSL Tunnel.